# how to make our website to be among ten in Google results?

Tags: search, google-analytics, seo, google-analytics-api

how to make our site viewable in top ten of the `Google search`...
I want my website to be available for the user who `Google` with search name social networking or something like ssit How to do that?

Comment: "Social networking", eh? Easy; just create something more popular than Facebook and Twitter.

Comment: SEO isn't really programming related. The few possible legal on-site optimizations will hardly get you into the top 10.

Comment: @Casey good webseite does it mean coding standard or more stuf in the project

Comment: @udaya I'm pretty sure Casey means "good" as in "popular". You probably won't be able to surpass your competition in the field of social networking anytime soon, though.

Comment: @Casey: May be you are right ..But we can try to br there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GET to know SEO(Search Engine Optimization).

1) Use proper relevant meta tag's keywords and description

2) Include title tag, get more important keyword in heading tags

3) Use proper title and alt for images

4) Have a page for site-map in your website

5) Have more back-links to your site by submitting articles, press release and news

6) Cross linking between pages of the same website to provide more links to most important pages may improve its visibility

But before anything one should know about the type of users they want for their site and search for the relevant keywords for their site, Google analytic definitely helps for this purpose.

And most important don't expect you site to be on the top soon, it will take some time like 6 month at least to get on the top of search engine. As soon as users of your site increase rank will increase. So BEST OF LUCK

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm used by Google gives a rank based on the number of other sites linking your site in association to specific keywords.

This has been spoofed to do so-called "google bombing": if a lot of people spread a link to a specific site using a specific word, they connect that word to that site and have the top rank (e.g., it has been used to associate insults to politics). The same technique has been used by spammers to rise the rank of garbage sites: they flood forums and blog comments with links to their sites. Although the algorithm has been improved to try to avoid this issue, it is still a viable way to raise the site rank.
It is clear that using such methods to improve visibility of your site will give a very bad reputation to your site.

I suggest instead to pay Google to advertise on it (so you will get top in a legitimate way).

*Of course, you are supposed to get the top ten if your site is **really** the top for the specific argument.*

Answer (score 0):

Slip google a fiver (cough) I mean, uh, get other well known websites to link to you. Google's Pagerank works out a pages final rank or priority by determining how many other sites link to it, with links that come from already high ranks sites being weighted more then links form a 'unknown' site.